# Manipulating a file in R

Tags: python, r, file

In Python:

```
fo = open("foo.txt", "r+")  
str = fo.read(10);  
position = fo.tell();  
print "Current file position : ", position
```

Is there a file pointer in  R? Can I know where the current file position is while I read the file?

Comment: The tasks most people want to achieve in R by reading a file (importing their datasets etc.) generally don't require this kind of file manipulation. If you have a strong reason for wanting to do this, perhaps you could explain exactly what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well to look at file-related functions you can try `?file` which tells you how to open a file and many file-related functions.

```
fo <- file('foo.txt', 'r+') // see  ?file for more details on the parameters
```

`fo` is a connection object that can be fed to other functions.
I recommend you read all of `?file`, which is very informative.

In particular, see the `See Also` and `Examples` sections.

In the `See Also`  section are listed a set of related functions for working with files.
In here it mentions (for example) `readLines`, `readBin` (to read binary files), `scan` (to read data into a vector or list) for reading files.

It also mentions `seek`. Looking at `?seek` you will see that

> `seek` with `where = NA` returns the current byte offset of a connection (from the beginning)

So try

```
seek(fo)
```

(Tip - the help files in R are very helpful! The 'See Also' section will tell you functions related to the one you are looking at, and the 'Examples' section will give you examples of how to use them. If you wanted to look up stuff to do with files and `?file` didn't work, you could always do `??file` which does a fuzzy search).